# How to close the iOS Captive Network Assistant Popup with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, captivenetwork

**Problem:** Captive Network Assistant on Apple devices is bring up the CNA screen with only a cancel button. Is there a way to close this window and/or redirect to safari by clicking on a link/javascript?

**Background Info:** Upon connecting to a wifi access point, users are redirected to a splash page. This splash page has links with target _blank to open in a new tab. The CNA login dialog breaks this functionality. Ideally, users would be prompted the CNA login, they would click continue, and it would load our splash page in safari and close the login dialog. Any information on how to do this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The captive network assistant is part of the system and out of reach of your application/website, so I doubt this is possible at all.

Comment: @Cyrille It currently loads my splash page within the CNA dialog. Is there any way to programatically close the wizard by submitting a form? I am just trying to figure out how other portals close this dialog after logging in.

Comment: The CNA is supposed to close itself automatically after you've successfully connected, isn't it? At least it always did for me, whatever the website.

Comment: @Cyrille Thats what I thought, however, on page load, I write a firewall rule that grants the client access, yet the CNA dialog persists even when it has connectivity.

Comment: @Cyrille After adding a link to itself, the button now displays done. The window will not close unless you click Done on the top right it looks like after a page reload.

Comment: This has been viewed 426 times at the time of my comment here.
I would love to get the bottom of this.

Comment: This has been viewed 426 times at the time of my comment here.
I would love to get the bottom of this.  Here are my findings (they will be unsatisfactory for you, as they are for me)... The captive network assistant in iOS7 uses a unique user agent with OMITS the word "safari"... This is the only real way to detect this unstoppable broken half browser.  It's not safari. It's some web-view of an app inside ios... Furthermore, there is no way to trigger the CNA in the xcode iphone simulator nor can you remote debug using safari dev tools as desktop safari fails to recognize it as debuggable!

Comment: @Pandem1c Bypassing the CNA from a maintainability standpoint, from my point of view, is a bad idea. Apple has changed the domains it pings for connectivity almost every major release of software. It is possible, I just wouldn't recommend it. User-agent detection is probably your best bet.

Comment: @fostah I agree with you. Bypassing it is a bad idea... But how to you develop a web-app to be used by it, when the CNA has it's own unique quirks, and can not be triggered in the simulator/ debugged by safari tools?

Comment: @Pandem1c check out JSConsole.com. You can remotely console.log, ie get the user-agent from the CNA. I explain how to do it in my answer near the bottom here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183295/console-log-not-working-in-an-ios-phonegap-3-0-app/23402890#23402890

Comment: I dont want to bypass anything. I'm not using authentication. I like the popup, saying "welcome, here are ou ToS". When they click "agree", I d like to open Safari on the go. My portal is captive.